# Geokit failing to return information from address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geokit

I'm trying to get the `suggested_bounds` from an address with GeoKit. This solution has worked, but all of a sudden it's started failing:

```
Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(location).suggested_bounds
```

That returns `nil`. When trying it without `suggested_bounds`, it returns this:

```
Street:
City:
State:
Zip:
Latitude:
Longitude:
Country:
Success: false
```

This has worked for months, and I've tried updating the Google API key with no luck.

If it helps, I can use the MultiGeocoder with IP addresses, but not actual addresses, like so:

```
Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(ip_address)
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Geokit previously used Google Maps API v2. That API has been depricated. To make Geokit use the new version with rails, update your geokit_config.rb file:

```
Geokit::Geocoders::provider_order = [:google3, :us]
Geokit::Geocoders::Google3Geocoder = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder3
```

See this issue for reference: https://github.com/geokit/geokit/issues/86

Comment: Where is that file ? I can't find it